# Combining Desktop Drag and Drop with Uploadify for Multi-Select

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, desktop, uploadify

I've been banging my head for a few days over this problem so I figured I'd look for some help here.

**BACKGROUND**
We've built a form where users can, amongst other things, upload files.  We have implemented desktop drag and drop for HTML5 users.  We're also using uploadify for traditional upload.  The ONLY reason we're using uploadify is to allow users of older browsers to multi-select files.  If it wasn't for the multi-select feature in older browsers, we would not be using any library for uploading and just use the new "multiple" attribute of the file input.

**PROBLEM**
I consider uploadify and desktop drag & drop 2 methods for basically doing the same thing which is allowing the user to give you an array files which they wish to upload.  Once this is done, I think both methods should call the same function, passing in the array of files intended for upload.  However, it seems that the file collection from uploadify is anatomically different than the file collection from drag and drop (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files).

So at this point, it looks like I have 2 options:
1)  Find a way to manually add the files collected from desktop drag and drop to the uploadify que and then call the upload method.

2)  Find a way to collect the selected (queued) files from uploadify and pass them to a separate ajax method (the same on the drag and drop files are passed to).  I almost got this working but, as I mentioned, the file objects are different.

Has anyone had to deal with this before?  Are there more elegant solutions that I'm missing here?  Any help would be appreciated.  I can add code samples if anyone needs it.

Comment: will you accept 3rd party solutions?

Comment: Sure.  As I mentioned we're already using a 3rd party solution (uploadify).  I'm just looking for one that plays nice with native solutions and is more accessible in terms of manually adding files to the queue or allowing us to manually extract files from the queue.  Either approach would be better than what I'm currently looking at which is building two completely separate upload protocols for desktop drag and drop vs uploadify.  Ideally I'd like to get the file array from the user and process the array the same way regardless of weather it was provided by drag and drop or uploadify.

Comment: Then, take a look at Uploadcare. service built around idea that no one have to suffer and reinvent file uploads :) So you can focus on your main functionality and leave handling files to us.